# depends.exe equivalent for Excel VBA Project

Tags: vba, com, excel, dll

depends.exe is an excellent tool that can analyse windows module dependencies, e.g. myexe.exe depends on dlla.dll, dllb.dll etc etc. The tool can tell you when there are missing dependecies which is a huge help when investigating machine specific issues.

Is there a tool/script/process that can do the same for Excel workbooks? Specifically, I want to see the dependency tree for the VBA references in my workbook, and see whats missing/different between machines.

FYI depends.exe is is available here:
http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: I've found a utility called 'ListDlls' [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656) which can show dll's in use by a particular process. This is a big help, as i can compare the dll's inuse by excel on one machine with another. However I would still like to find something that can identify missing dependencies like depends.exe...

Answer (score 1):

> > > I want to see the dependency tree for the VBA references in my workbook

nickos556, When you open a VBA Project in Excel, It gives you an error if there is any dependency missing.

If you click on Tools | References then you can see the entire list of references.

[image]

In case any reference is missing then it gives you this snapshot. If you notice, it mentions the path of the missing dll at the bottom.

[image]

Hope this is what you wanted?

Sid

Comment: Hi sid! Thanks for the help. Yep I know about the 'missing' dialog box, but in my  case I don't see anything 'missing'.  Thats why I want to dig deeper... thanks